# Unable to click link inside div using robot framework (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

so i have a problem with clicking a link inside a divs . even if i give 1 minute of sleep and eventhough the screen is fully loaded the action of clicking the link is not performed

actually this link or anchor tag is placed inside 4 div's and inside anchor tag there are 2 Span .

checked xpath , while giving on chropath extension it is pointing to exact location where i have to click . but while running it is giving me an error

Due to certain reason i will not be able to show HTML content here .

and here is my code

```
Selecting_Value
    sleep  50 sec

    Click Link   xpath://a[@id='ext-comp-1059']
    sleep   10 sec
    Click Link   xpath://a[@id='tabItem-1063-itemEl']
    sleep  20 sec
    Click Link  xpath://a[@id='tabItem-1066-itemEl']

    sleep   20 sec
```

and it throws me this error :

ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (292, 71). Other element would receive the click:

(Session info: MicrosoftEdge=88.0.705.56)

and even if i give Click Element   xpath://div[@id='toolbar-1035-targetEl'] which is the first div , it is not working .

Do anyone have any idea regarding this

Comment: please add httml or website link

Comment: Sorry it was actually Mouse Over and Not Click Link